# Сделать ссылки в тексте кликабельными

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)option:(id)sender {

BOOL useCustomView = NO;

RNBlurModalView *modal;
if (useCustomView) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 5.f;

    modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithView:view];
}
else {
    modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithTitle:@"О приложении" message:@"Фотографии предоставлены ххххх https://www.google.ru "];

    modal.defaultHideBlock = ^{
        NSLog(@"Code called after the modal view is hidden");
    };
}
//    modal.dismissButtonRight = YES;
[modal show];
```

}

Вот такой код, как сделать, чтобы гугл кликался и открывался через сафари?
Спасибо.

Вот что в RNBlurModalView, когда меняю UILabel на UITextView, вылезают восемь ошибок, которые могу решить только удалением строк. Не подскажете, как там заменить?

```
    + (UIView*)generateModalViewWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message {
CGFloat defaultWidth = 280.f;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, defaultWidth, 0);
CGFloat padding = 10.f;
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.816 green:0.788 blue:0.788 alpha:1.000];

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.8f];
view.layer.borderColor = whiteColor.CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 2.f;
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, defaultWidth - padding * 2.f, 0)];
titleLabel.text = title;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.f];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[titleLabel autoHeight];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
titleLabel.top = padding;
[view addSubview:titleLabel];

UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, defaultWidth - padding * 2.f, 0)];
messageLabel.text = message;
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.f];
messageLabel.textColor = titleLabel.textColor;
messageLabel.shadowOffset = titleLabel.shadowOffset;
messageLabel.shadowColor = titleLabel.shadowColor;
messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[messageLabel autoHeight];
messageLabel.top = titleLabel.bottom + padding;
[view addSubview:messageLabel];

view.height = messageLabel.bottom + padding;

view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

return view;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется унаследоваться от RNBlurModalView и переписать тайтл, вместо UILabel заменить на UITextVIew и включить функцию:

```
textview.editable = NO; 
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Или заюзать вот такой класс [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Comment: Спасибо, оба способа пока сложны для меня, не поможете, см. код выше.